# Proper deployment of AAD Pod Identity

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-rm-template, aad-pod-identity

I intend to use AAD Pod Identity so that my kubernetes workloads can leverage managed identities that I create in Azure.

Currently, I create my identities and role assignment through ARM templates. Afterwards, I need to create an instance of the `AzureIdentity` CRD, which contains a reference to the `clientId` of the managed identity.

I come from another cloud provider which didn't need a CRD to act on behalf of a service account, so I was wondering what's the best practice for managing this configuration?

Ideally I would like to stay within the realm of ARM templates so I wouldn't have to split up a cluster deployment in several places. However, I don't have an idea of how this would work since I need to generate a yaml that contains a reference to something that comes from other ARM templates. What's a proper way to automate this without having to crack open a script to do queries via the az cli:

1. Deploy managed cluster + managed identities via ARM template
2. Create an `Azure Identity` that is bound to one of those managed identities

I'm not sure if this  is possible, but would love to see what others have done.

Comment: Do you mean something like have an output from one ARM template then use it in the next one?

Comment: Not exactly. I know it's possible do that using `output` field and `reference` functions with linkedTemplates. I'm more curious about the creating the `AzureIdentity` CRD on the kubernetes side of things. Like I find my yaml definitions have to depend on things that are dynamically created with arm templates

Comment: Unfortunately in my case, as ARM doesn't support everything so I end up writing some script to complete the ARM work.